# Error with composer when trying to install Facebook Ads API. Wrong Package Number?

Tags: facebook-php-sdk, composer-php

I am trying to install Facbeook Ads API following the tutorial here: [Facebook Ads API SDK](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-ads-sdk)
but when I run composer I get the following error:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - The requested package facebook/php-ads-sdk 1.0.0 could not be found.
```

As you can see, composer is looking for package 1.0.0 while on my json I have the following code:

```
{
    "name": "facebook/php-ads-sdk",
    "description": "PHP SDK for Facebook ads",
    "type": "library",
    "license": "Facebook Platform",
    "keywords": [
      "facebook",
      "ads",
      "sdk"
    ],
    "homepage": "https://developers.facebook.com/",
    "require-dev" : {
        "phpunit/phpunit": ">=4.0.0"

    },

    "require": {
        "facebook/php-ads-sdk": "2.2.*"
    },

    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "FacebookAds\\": "src/FacebookAds/"
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You called your package the **same name** as the package you're trying to require (`facebook/php-ads-sdk`).

Composer is getting confused by that naming conflict. You should **name your package something unique** to you like `jordanbelf/facebook-ads`.

Also, it looks like you copied the `composer.json` file from the `php-ads-sdk` repository. There's a lot of stuff in there you don't need. Your `composer.json` file could be stripped down to:

```json
{
    "name": "jordanbelf/facebook-ads",
    "require": {
        "facebook/php-ads-sdk": "2.2.*"
    }
}
```